# Twint Module and creating a dataframe from tweets

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I have an issue converting twint results into a dataframe. I am unable to fetch the tweet results and store it into a dataframe. Everytime I set c.Pandas=True I get an error. Any ideas how to resolve this.

I know i can always store it to json/csv then port it back in but want to avoid doing that.

Code I am using:

```
import twint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import nest_asyncio
import pandas as pd
nest_asyncio.apply()

c = twint.Config()
c.Limit=10
c.Username='ProtonMail'
c.Store_object=True
c.Pandas=True
twint.run.Search(c)
```

error Log below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-e0414b83fe16>", line 17, in <module>
    twint.run.Search(c)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 292, in Search
    run(config, callback)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 213, in run
    get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main(callback))

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 61, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 251, in __step
    result = coro.throw(exc)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 154, in main
    await task

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 260, in __await__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 318, in __wakeup
    future.result()

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 249, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 198, in run
    await self.tweets()

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\run.py", line 145, in tweets
    await output.Tweets(tweet, self.config, self.conn)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\output.py", line 142, in Tweets
    await checkData(tweets, config, conn)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\output.py", line 116, in checkData
    panda.update(tweet, config)

  File "c:\users\xx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\twint\storage\panda.py", line 67, in update
    day = weekdays[strftime("%A", localtime(Tweet.datetime))]

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You just need to retrieve the saved search from `twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df` and store it in a variable.

```
import twint
import pandas

c = twint.Config()
c.Pandas = True
c.Lang = 'en'
c.Username='ProtonMail'
c.Limit=10
twint.run.Search(c)
test_df = twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df
```

see https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/173 for more info

If it helps, I am using twint version 2.1.21 on python 3.7, downloaded using command
`pip install git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint` on anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, removing "store object" and "pandas = true" and replacing them by the code below (c.Store_csv, c.Custom_csv) worked for me. You should write the entire path for the ouptut as well.

```
import twint
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

# Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "data science"
c.Store_csv = True
c.Custom_csv = ["id", "user_id", "username", "tweet"]
c.Output = ("C:\Users\name\Downloads\tweet`enter code here`.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `twint.run.Search(c)`, fist you need to define `c.Search= ""`with the text you want to search. But if you are interested to scrape the tweet from the profile of `ProtonMail`, you should run `twint.run.Profile(c)` instead. Depending on the type of data you need, there are differnt options to run (Read more at this [reference on github](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/wiki/Tweet-attributes).).